# select specific child div:ntn-child

Tags: css

I am trying to select only the fifth div
of 8 divs inside a div called #hoyre

```
#hoyre > div:ntn-child(5){
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: typo? use nth instead of ntn: #hoyre > div:nth-child(5){

Comment: Just a typo: it is `nth-child` not `ntn-child`

Comment: use web develoepr tool, open the page with chrome then press F12, find which div you want to edit, then press + button from the right panel and check for how it creates, you are probably missing something with the signature.                                                              http://i.imgur.com/QHH0TLB.jpg

Comment: Also if the 5 child is not a div it will not light up try * instead of div.

Comment: @null By the way there is an off-topic close option of "a simple typographical error", you don't have to specify a custom reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a mispelling

`ntn-child(5)` should be **`nth-child(5)`**

Comment: You should try to format your code better including proper capitalization, code blocks, and complete sentences

Comment: Thanks Zach, I probably wont fix this one. Feel free to edit this for me.

Comment: of course (red in face) :-)
this solved my problem.
thank you for your help.